# How can I configure firefox to not clear gmail cookies while using strict content blocking?

Tags: firefox, gmail, cookies

Since the recent content blocking feature, which appeared some months ago (there already was another content blocking feature, but it was different), gmail is not saving cookies anymore with 2 factor authentication, so I have to receive a SMS each time.

I've configured my browser to delete cookies after closing firefox, and I've set exceptions with https://mail.google.com/ and account.google.com so that they are not deleted.